# Not creating classes or linking files, but getting 'undefined reference' error with single void function

Tags: c++

I've searched and read a lot of the posts on here in regards to this error, but they all seem to be about linking files together or messing with creating classes. I'm doing neither. It's just a simple program with one function besides main. Here's the error I'm getting in my compiler, not specific to any line of code:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "delete_repeats(char*, int&)", referenced from:
      _main in ETest.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

And here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void delete_repeats(char arr[], int& length);
int main()
{
    char b;
    int length = 0;
    char arr[80] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    {
            cin.get(b);
            arr[i] = b;
            length += 1;
    }
    cout << endl << length << endl
    << arr << endl << arr << endl;
    delete_repeats(arr, length);
    cout << arr << endl << length;

    return 0;
}
void delete_repeats(char arr[], int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k < length; k++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[k])
            {
                for (int j = k; j < length; j++)
                {
                    arr[k] = arr[k+1];
                }
                arr[length -1] = 0;
                length -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error above is when I try to submit it in myprogramminglab.com
When I try to build it in codeblocks it gives me the same error, but with less detail, just "undefined reference to 'delete_repeats(char*, int&)'

I have made numerous programs at this point that use similar functions but this is the first time I've encountered this error. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can you help me out, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`void delete_repeats(char arr[], int length)`

to

`void delete_repeats(char arr[], int& length)`

What's going on is that you're declaring a function, `void delete_repeats(char arr[], int& length);` (notice the second parameter is passed by reference, that's what `&` means in this context).

Then, you're trying to define that function as `void delete_repeats(char arr[], int length);` (notice how the second parameter is passed by value) but really you're declaring and defining an overload with the same name.

Your linker expects a definition to be provided for the first declaration but never gets it. Instead, it sees a new declaration (the second one) with an associated definition and links that one correctly. The undefined reference error is your linker telling you it can't find the definition for the first declaration.

Comment: D'oh! Must have been staring at it for too long to miss such a simple discrepancy. Thanks!

Comment: @ConfuciusSays No problem! If that solved your problem, make sure to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: @AnthonyVallée-Dubois Note that an answer cannot be marked as accepted until after 15 minutes of the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing an `int&` in your function definition:

```
void delete_repeats(char arr[], int& length) {   }
//                                ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the reference symbol in function definition.

You've defined the function as:

```
  void delete_repeats(char arr[], int& length);
```

But later defined it as:

```
  void delete_repeats(char arr[], int length)
```

Parameter length is declared as `int&` in the former but plain `int` in the latter.